# What can I do to keep my list from scrolling when I click search?

Tags: html, css

What can I do to keep my list from scrolling when I click search?

codepen:
codepen.io/Lubanskakinga/pen/mdjXVEK?editors=1100

Answer (score 2):

Since it is a flexible structure, when the search-txt width increases, it scrolls in other divs. If you add Position:absolute and right:0 this problem goes away.

```
.search-txt {
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  ..
  ..
}
```